New mac usb type c keyboard arrived. There's no fn key?
I have a USB C charge touch id keyboard with no keypad.

Magic Keyboard with Touch ID for Mac models with Apple silicon (USB–C) - US English


The lightning one and this type c one look identical but theres no fn key. so i can't seem to change the volume (i use have "use dedicated function row" setting enabled in settings)
am i missing the fn key?

How to use the function keys on your Mac: “Press and hold the Function (Fn)/Globe key  while pressing a function key.”

The key in the bottom left corner, with the "globe" icon, is the Fn key.

It appears a bug might be present in macOS versions before Sequoia 15.1 (24B83) causing this. Upgrade your OS may help solve this, too.

Yep. This was not working. I did install Sequoia 15.1 (24B83) as of this morning and now the globe key works as a function key again. Phew!
